# How to print a multi-line match?

Tags: command-line, search, linux, ex-mode, multiple-lines

I've a file where I would like to extract a multiline pattern in non-greedy way (similar to this [scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/q/152708/55075)) by using `ex` editor.

This example works fine:

```
$ ex +'/aa/,/cc/p' -scq! <(echo -e "start\naa\nbb\ncc\nend")
aa
bb
cc
```

by extracting me pattern between `aa` and `cc`, but it's uses ranges.

And I would like to extend that example by introducing [a multiline non-greedy pattern](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_across_multiple_lines#Searching_for_multiline_HTML_comments) (`\_.\{-}`), but it doesn't print for me the whole multi-line match for some reason:

```
$ ex +'/aa\_.\{-}cc/p' -scq! <(echo -e "start\naa\nbb\ncc\nend")
aa
```

Is there any reason for that or I'm missing anything? How do I correct that?

Comment: `:p` only works on single lines and does not understand multiline patterns. Therefore use ranges. That's what they are for and they are non-greedy by default. (This is also the way sed works)

Comment: Is their another way to do multi line search without having to use ex command, more specifically in the command mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's something almost perverse in doing this with `ex`, akin to chopping a tree with a razor blade, or drinking a bucket of water through a straw.  But if you stop and think for a few minutes about what you're doing, it's relatively straightforward:

```
ex +'/aa\_.\{-}cc/' +'normal gny' +new +'normal P' +'%p' -scqa! file
```

Translation, for the less masochistic among us:

- `+` introduce command line statements that apply to `file`
- `/aa\_.\{-}cc/` searches for the pattern
- `normal gn` marks the text just found
- `y` yanks said text
- `new` opens a new buffer
- `normal P` pastes the text
- `%p` prints the buffer (i.e. `:p` applied to the entire buffer, a.k.a. `%`)
- `-scqa!` runs `:qa!`, i.e. bails out.

The same tricks, using `normal <mumble>` to get to normal mode commands from within `ex`, and pasting stuff to a scratch buffer, can be used to solve other similar quizzes, such as printing the contents of a register, and `echo`-ing things (hint: use `redir` for that one).

**Edit:** Alternative approach, by OP:

```
ex +'sil /aa\_.\{-}cc/norm gny' +'redi>>/dev/stdout|echon @"' -scq! file
```

Please note that `/dev/stdout` is not available on all systems.