# How to store all occurrences of a multiline search in a register?

Tags: search, register, multiple-lines

I'm not sure if I've failed at searching for the answer to this, but now I've worked it out I wanted to document it here. The problem is searching for a multiline pattern, and storing all such occurrences in a register.

I am trying to look for calls to a particular function, e.g. `func(a, b, c);`, so that I can extract them to a separate file. I'm doing this in Vim (rather than using, say, sed or awk), because I find Vim's searching over multiple lines syntax easiest.

If I search for a pattern, I know I can store the line(s) containing the results in a register:

```
:let @a=''
:g/func\s*([^;]*;/y A
```

Stores all the single line calls to `func` in `@a`.

Unfortunately, this doesn't quite work if I adapt this search pattern to find multiple line calls:

`/func\s*(\_.\{-\};` matches multi-line calls such as:

```
func(a, b,
c,
d);
```

-- no matter how many new lines/parameters are in the way, but the corresponding global command `:g/func\s*(\_.\{-\};/y A` just stores the first line of each match. I can sort of understand why this happens (`y` yanks the line the result is on, and doesn't know it takes multiple lines).

How can I adapt the command to store all lines of each occurrence in a register?

Comment: Similar: [How can I yank multiple lines into a register?](https://superuser.com/q/234317/87805)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out something along these lines works (although there might well be better ways) -- using a substitute-without-substituting command instead of a global command:

Starting with the answer here: [How to show all unique types of a pattern?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/8906/how-to-show-all-unique-types-of-a-pattern#8914)

```
:%s/[A-Za-z]*\>/\=add(b:types, submatch(0))/ng
```

I went with:

```
let @a=''
:%s/func\s*(\_[^;]\{-\};/\=setreg('A', submatch(0)."\n")/ng
```

Which stores all the calls, even the entirety of multi-line ones. because the A is capitalised, it's appended, as before. The "n" means to not actually do a substitute, and for completeness "g" means all occurrences on each line.

**EDIT:** Previously I'd tried appending `'\n'` or `'\r'` to put each match on a new line -- but they came out literally. Instead appending `"\n"` puts each match on a new line. Thanks to @Jair for the new line fix -- I didn't know single and double quotes were different, and didn't think to try the other!

Comment: You're almost done. Just replace `'\n'` with `"\n"`. 
Read [What is the difference between single and double quoted
strings?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/9706/6698)

Comment: Brilliant -- thanks, @Jair. I'll wait a bit to see if anyone suggests a better method (it was the first time I'd come across the `n` option to `substitute` -- it feels a bit odd to use a substitute to not do a substitute! Then again, the option's there...)

Answer (score 2):

To yank a last multiline search pattern into register with [a multiline non-greedy pattern](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_across_multiple_lines#Searching_for_multiline_HTML_comments), try:

```
/func(\_.\{-});/norm gn"iy
```

then you'll have your yanked multiline pattern (between `func(` and `);`) in your `@i` register (print by `echo @i`).

Here is the command line example as per this [post](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/5148/467) given `func.txt` input file:

```
$ ex +'sil /func\_.\{-});/norm gny' +'redi>>/dev/stdout|echon @"' -scq! func.txt
func(a, b,
c,
d);
```

Related:

- [How to print a multi-line match?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/5144/467)
- [How can I yank multiple lines into a register?](https://superuser.com/q/234317/87805)