# When searching and replacing can I store a capture group to a register?

Tags: replace, register

This is similar but I am unable to draw the information I need from it: [How to store all occurrences of a multiline search in a register?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/11791/how-to-store-all-occurrences-of-a-multiline-search-in-a-register)

I have these lines

```
###################              trim 8 seconds from the end of           ####################  
###################             the file and keep everything else         ####################
```

Which when I select the above lines in visual mode, press `<esc>` then run this command

```
:*s/\v\s{0,5}([#]{1,30})([a-zA-Z0-9 ]{1,100})([#]{1,30})\s{0,5}/\1     \3
```

I get these lines:

The replacement expression simply replaces the text and not the beginnig and ending #'s or any preceeding or training white space

```
###################         ####################  
###################         ####################
```

The reason I do this is to copy the #'s signs so I can quickly re-use them for labeling header sections of script.

You can see I have the text as the number `\2` capture group.

Can I store capture group `\2` to a register for easy re-use in this command?

Can I string this all together somehow by combining
`:norm: Vj` (selects the two lines) +
`:%s/\v\s{0,5}([#]{1,30})([a-zA-Z0-9 ]{1,100})([#]{1,30})\s{0,5}/\1     \3`
into a one liner?

Comment: As far as storing the group, how would that work considering it could have different values for different matched lines?

Comment: @BLayer Thanks, that's really helpful. I know about magic mode `\v`, but did'nt want to start using it until I was more fully aware of the intracies of escaping. I also have a slow memory which often works 5 - 10 mins after I actually need it! Thanks all the same - it's setting me in the right direction :)

Comment: `[\s]` is the same as `s`. If you want to match a sequence of zero to five white-space characters just use `\s{0,5\}` (or `\s{0,5}` if the pattern is preceded with `\v`).

Comment: @BLayer Good point about multiple lines. I don't know. Is one line possible as a starter?

Comment: @JürgenKrämer Thanks! Is the escaped \ necessary before the last `}`?

Comment: @Blayer Fair point about decyphering the regex. I will remember for this forum. (In some forums the fullest picture seems to be demanded up front)

Comment: @Kes No, it's not. I tend to use `\{...\}` just for reasons of symmetry with `\(...\)` where it is necessary.

Comment: @Blayer Sorry, I wasn't clear. I mean what about if only one line is selected and not the two described, is it then possible to store capture group `\2` to a register?

Comment: @Blayer I'm definatley not omniscient. No where even near. I did'nt realise initially that 2 lines wouldn't work, now simply curious to see if case for one line would work. That's all I meant, unless I missed something, thanks

Comment: @BLayer lol haha, you had me there!

Comment: I got this one liner working inside my `.vimrc` file. It selects the single line under the cursor and uses magic mode for ease in the replacement regex, `nnoremap <c-l> 0V<esc>:*s/\v\s{0,5}([#]{1,30})([a-zA-Z0-9 ]{1,100})([#]{1,30})\s{0,5}/\1     \3/<cr><esc>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several things here, some answers, some tricks (?)

- visual mode, Escape, `:*` is exactly equivalent to visual mode, `:` (notice the `:'<,'>` markers got inserted; this is a `:help [range]` for visual mode, which is what `:*` is equivalent to). I just find typing one character (`:`) faster :)
- since most commands (like `:substitute`) take a range, if you learn how to write ranges, you can avoid visual mode (or at least combine the steps)

  - for example, instead of `Vj:s/…`, you could write `:,+s/…` (since the default on the left side of the comma is `.`, and the `+` gives one line down)
- if you want to save the `#` header markers, I would make a command that inserts them:

```
:command -nargs=1 Header normal! I################### <args> ####################
```

- to actually save the capture group is a little complicated: we need to use the expression sub-replace `\=` to call `setreg()` with `submatch(2)`, but we want to ignore its return value and use the other submatches as the final result. Fortunately, AFAICT, `setreg` always returns 0? That means we can treat it like it's falsy and use a conditional expression. Here's the full idea:

  1. Clear out the target register (e.g., `qaq`)
  2. For each line in the substitute, use `setreg()` with the capitalized register to append (also include a newline, for separation), *but* "return" the value of `submatch(1).'   '.submatch(3)`
  3. `put a` or `"ap` or whatever you needed to do with the text

In full:

```
qaq
" visual select, or type a range, whatever
:substitute/\v\s{0,5}([#]{1,30})([a-zA-Z0-9 ]{1,100})([#]{1,30})\s{0,5}/\=setreg('A', submatch(2)."\n") ? '' : submatch(1).'     '.submatch(3)
:register a
```

with output

```
Type name  Content
  l  "a    8 seconds left in overtime ^J other text here ^J              trim 8 seconds from the end of           ^J             the file and keep everything else         ^J
```

Comment: @Ben Thank you for a superb answer, I will be digesting it a few times over the next short while to make sure I understand it all. I've had a detailed read, and checked out `:help [ranges]` and will be doing so again :)

Comment: @Ben your answer has come in handy again, thanks! I just used a nice variant of your answer to add 1 to each number at the start of each row in a visual text selection `:*s/\(^[0-9]\{1,3\}\)\(.*\)/\=(submatch(1) + 1). submatch(2)`

Comment: @Kes great! If this solved your original problem, you can indicate that by accepting the answer